# CSS reset does not allow a different vertical align

Tags: css

I used a css reset where * selector has

```
vertical-align:baseline;
```

Entire theme was build with it, and now, at the very end, I need one div to align top. And it does not. I did specify it in styling, added !important. No luck. I'm sure I'm missing something, but can't figure out what.

So
Css reset * selector part looks like this

```
* {
vertical-align: baseline;
font-weight: inherit;
font-family: inherit;
font-style: inherit;
font-size: 100%;
border: 0 none;
outline: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

Html part 
    
    
         
            
     php part of wordpress templates

```
                   <li>
 <div id="datencomments">
           <div id="date3">
            <div id="datetxt">
               <div class="month"><?php the_time('M ') ?></div>
               <div class="day"><?php the_time('j ') ?></div>
           </div></div>
           <div id="comments"><span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( '1 Comment', 'blankslate' ), __( '% Comments', 'blankslate' ) ); ?></span></div>
 </div>
           </li>
 </ul>  
 </div>
```

css for it.

```
.postpreview ul {
list-style: none;
}

.postpreview ul li {
display: inline-block;
}

#datencomments {
width: 100px;
vertical-align: top !important;
 }

#date3 {
width:100px;
height: 100px;
border: 2px solid transparent;
border-radius: 100px;
background-color: #17B1BE;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
}

.month {
text-align: center;
margin-top: 12px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: 200;
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
 }

 .day {
text-align: center;
margin-top: -8px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  }

 #comments {
margin-top: 20px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
font-style: italic;
text-decoration: underline;
 }
```

the rest is transitions, hover colors etc...

I need #datencomments at the top of the template, while * is pulling it down.

Comment: Need to see more of your CSS.

Comment: ... and the bit of HTML to which it's being applied.

Comment: divs are by default block level elements and won't respond to `vertical-align`. My guess is that you'll have to `position: absolute` it, but I cant say for sure without some example code

Comment: If you're trying to verticly align the content inside the div, you probably need line-height equal to the height of the div.  That will only work if you only have one line.  We really need more information to help you.

Comment: It could be that you need to specify the `line-height` of that particular `div`

Answer (score 1):

If done like this, display:block puts the text behind the box, display:inline puts it inside on top and display:inline-block puts the text where it is specified with vertical-align.

```
    <div id='container'>
      <div id='text'>This is a test</div>
    </div>

    #container{
      height: 200px;border: 5px solid blue;text-align:center;
    }

    #text,#container:before{
      vertical-align: middle;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    #container:before{
      content: "";
      height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: They are displayed in block. In fact, it's ul. I'll add a bit more code in a sec.